# How to enter these symbols on a computer

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am reading a book, and I need to recreate these symbols. So far, I have only gotten the first one(on MathType) and need the one that looks like a beta. How can I get these symbols in an editable form?
[Symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29vUo.png)

Comment: I recommend you look at this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), it should help you.

Comment: For Latex, you can use [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html). (Though I'm having trouble in making it recognize mathfrak P consistently)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Fraktur A and P there.

$\mathfrak{A, P}$

In Tex/Latex you get these by using a command such as

`\mathfrak{A, P}`

Comment: When I copy the second one, it just shows up as P

Comment: You need to use the \mathfrak{} command to type them. typing \mathfrak{A} gives $$ \mathfrak{A}$$

Comment: When you say "recreate", recreate how, exactly? If you're using Tex or related software (e.g. Latex), use the code which I used to compose my answer, not just the letter P.